# How to install a specific kernel version?

Tags: 14.04, kernel, updates

yesterday I updated the kernel version to `4.2.0-42-generic` through update manager. This unlucky event caused nvidia drivers to stop working, resulting in the famous [login loop issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop), after rebooting.

Today I found the same problem, for the very same reason, was reported in [this launchpad bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-361/+bug/1603652) few days ago.

Trying to fix that I messed things up a little bit, so I backed up my data and reinstalled ubuntu 14 without internet connection, which has kernel `4.2.0-27-generic`. is there a way to manually upgrade to kernel `4.2.0-41-generic`? maybe through apt?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There was no need to re-install. You could simply boot with a previous kernel using grub menu.

Now kernel 4.2.0-41 is not available in the repositories.

If you are using Ubuntu 14.04, you can install kernel 4.4 by running

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-xenial
```

Also the problem with Nvidia could appear because you did not disable Secure Boot in BIOS. With new kernels it is required to use propritary drivers.

Comment: I actually did disable the secure boot. anyway, today I realised it was a kernel problem, not a driver problem,  but I already messed up and needed to reinstall. any guarantee 4.4 is not going to interfere with nvidia drivers?

Comment: Nvidia drivers work OK with 4.4. This kernel will be default in a couple of weeks in Ubuntu 14.04.5 with the same drivers. There is no 100% guarantee. But you need to learn booting with different kernels without re-installing the system. I am using this kernel with Nvidia.